# What are the names associated with Python Tkinter get_focus()?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Tkinter script that has multiple Entry widgets.  I have a method that gets the Entry widget that has "focus": i.e. `focused = self.root.focus_get()`  This will return something like this: `.!labelframe2.!entry`

What I really need to know is

1. The name of the `tk.StringVar()` used for the `textvariable` in the Entry widget
2. The name of the `tk.Entry` widget

If you try this code, simply mouse click in any of the Entry widgets and the click the "Who Has Focus" button.

```
# focus_get.py

import tkinter as tk

class Focus_Get:
    def __init__(self):
        #Create the root window
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry('300x800')
        self.root.title('Focus_Get')

        #Create a frame
        self.f1 = tk.LabelFrame(self.root,text='This Is The First Frame')
        self.f1.pack(pady=10)
        self.f1e1 = tk.StringVar()
        self.f1e2 = tk.StringVar()

        self.f1e1_label = tk.Label(self.f1,text='Frame 1 Entry 1',).pack(padx=5,pady=5)
        self.f1e1_entry = tk.Entry(self.f1,textvariable=self.f1e1,width='7')
        self.f1e1_entry.pack(pady=5)

        self.f1e2_label = tk.Label(self.f1,text='Frame 1 Entry 2').pack(padx=5,pady=5)
        self.f1e2_entry = tk.Entry(self.f1,textvariable=self.f1e2,width='7')
        self.f1e2_entry.pack(pady=5)

        self.f2 = tk.LabelFrame(self.root,text='This Is The Second Frame')
        self.f2.pack(pady=10)
        self.f2e1 = tk.StringVar()
        self.f2e2 = tk.StringVar()

        self.f2e1_label = tk.Label(self.f2,text='Frame 2 Entry 1').pack(padx=5,pady=5)
        self.f2e1_entry = tk.Entry(self.f2,textvariable=self.f2e1,width='7')
        self.f2e1_entry.pack(pady=5)

        self.f2e2_label = tk.Label(self.f2,text='Frame 2 Entry 2').pack(padx=5,pady=5)
        self.f2e2_entry = tk.Entry(self.f2,textvariable=self.f2e2,width='7')
        self.f2e2_entry.pack(pady=5)

        self.f3 = tk.LabelFrame(self.root,text='This Is The Button Frame')
        self.f3.pack(pady=10)
        self.btn1 = tk.Button(self.f3,text='Who Has Focus',command=self.show_focus).pack(pady=5)
        self.btn2 = tk.Button(self.f3,text='Clear',command=self.clear_focus).pack(pady=5)
        self.btn3 = tk.Button(self.f3,text='Exit',command=self.close_it,).pack(pady=5)

        self.who_text = tk.Listbox(self.root,width=18,height=8,font=('Arial',16))
        self.who_text.pack(pady=5)

        self.root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.close_it)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def show_focus(self):
        focused = self.root.focus_get()
        self.who_text.insert(tk.END,focused)
        # What I really need to know is
        # 1) The name of the tk.StringVar() used for the textvariable in the Entry widget (i.e. self.f1e1....self.f2e2)
        # 2) The name of the tl.Entry widget (i.e. self.f1e1_entry.....self.f2e2_entry)

    def clear_focus(self):
        self.root.focus()
        self.who_text.delete(0,tk.END)

    def close_it(self):
        self.root.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Focus_Get()
```

Comment: `self.root.nametowidget(focused)` (this can be called on any widget) would turn something like `".!labelframe2.!entry"` into the actual Entry object.  I don't know of any way to get the StringVar, though - the widget only knows about the Tcl name of the var, it doesn't know anything about the Python name.

Comment: There is no point of getting the name of the variable that store the reference of the `Entry` widget because there may be more than one variable referencing the widget, for example `a = b = tk.Entry(...)`, there are two variables `a` and `b` referencing the widget.  You should state clear what you want to achieve by getting the name of the variable.

Comment: I'm wanting to get() the value of the Entry widget, concatenate to it, and set() it to the new value.  I am writing an on screen numeric keypad for an applet that has multiple Entry widgets.  I have a working solution, but was hoping I could dynamically determine the  StringVar names and the Entry widget name instead of hard coding.  I need the Entry widget name to advance the cursor after each concatenation ( .icursor).  I only need keys 0-9 & .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the purpose of getting the python variable name is so that you can then get the object itself, just use the `focus_get()` function:

```py
focused = self.root.focus_get()
```

Alternatively, if you want the name for other purposes, you can simply store the name in a variable on each object, and then look up the name in your `show_focus` function. It's klunky, but it's quick and dirty and works. Essentially, add the following lines to each `Entry` object (changing the string to match the variable name, of course):

```py
self.f2e1_entry.stringvar_name = 'f2e1'
self.f2e1_entry.entry_name = 'f2e1_entry'
```

Then, in your `show_focus()` function, use `focus_get` to get the object, and use `getattr` to get the name:

```py
if hasattr(focused, 'stringvar_name'):
    stringvar_name = getattr(focused, 'stringvar_name')
    self.who_text.insert(tk.END, 'tk.StringVar(): ' + stringvar_name)
if hasattr(focused, 'entry_name'):
    entry_name = getattr(focused, 'entry_name')
    self.who_text.insert(tk.END, 'tl.Entry : ' + entry_name)
```

Everything put together becomes this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

class Focus_Get:
    def __init__(self):
        #Create the root window
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry('300x800')
        self.root.title('Focus_Get')

        #Create a frame
        self.f1 = tk.LabelFrame(self.root,text='This Is The First Frame')
        self.f1.pack(pady=10)
        self.f1e1 = tk.StringVar()
        self.f1e2 = tk.StringVar()

        self.f1e1_label = tk.Label(self.f1,text='Frame 1 Entry 1',).pack(padx=5,pady=5)
        self.f1e1_entry = tk.Entry(self.f1,textvariable=self.f1e1,width='7')
        self.f1e1_entry.stringvar_name = 'f1e1'
        self.f1e1_entry.entry_name = 'f1e1_entry'
        self.f1e1_entry.pack(pady=5)

        self.f1e2_label = tk.Label(self.f1,text='Frame 1 Entry 2').pack(padx=5,pady=5)
        self.f1e2_entry = tk.Entry(self.f1,textvariable=self.f1e2,width='7')
        self.f1e2_entry.stringvar_name = 'f1e2'
        self.f1e2_entry.entry_name = 'f1e2_entry'
        self.f1e2_entry.pack(pady=5)

        self.f2 = tk.LabelFrame(self.root,text='This Is The Second Frame')
        self.f2.pack(pady=10)
        self.f2e1 = tk.StringVar()
        self.f2e2 = tk.StringVar()

        self.f2e1_label = tk.Label(self.f2,text='Frame 2 Entry 1').pack(padx=5,pady=5)
        self.f2e1_entry = tk.Entry(self.f2,textvariable=self.f2e1,width='7')
        self.f2e1_entry.stringvar_name = 'f2e1'
        self.f2e1_entry.entry_name = 'f2e1_entry'
        self.f2e1_entry.pack(pady=5)

        self.f2e2_label = tk.Label(self.f2,text='Frame 2 Entry 2').pack(padx=5,pady=5)
        self.f2e2_entry = tk.Entry(self.f2,textvariable=self.f2e2,width='7')
        self.f2e2_entry.stringvar_name = 'f2e2'
        self.f2e2_entry.entry_name = 'f2e2_entry'
        self.f2e2_entry.pack(pady=5)

        self.f3 = tk.LabelFrame(self.root,text='This Is The Button Frame')
        self.f3.pack(pady=10)
        self.btn1 = tk.Button(self.f3,text='Who Has Focus',command=self.show_focus).pack(pady=5)
        self.btn2 = tk.Button(self.f3,text='Clear',command=self.clear_focus).pack(pady=5)
        self.btn3 = tk.Button(self.f3,text='Exit',command=self.close_it,).pack(pady=5)

        self.who_text = tk.Listbox(self.root,width=18,height=8,font=('Arial',16))
        self.who_text.pack(pady=5)

        self.root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.close_it)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def show_focus(self):
        focused = self.root.focus_get()
        if hasattr(focused, 'stringvar_name'):
            stringvar_name = getattr(focused, 'stringvar_name')
            self.who_text.insert(tk.END, 'tk.StringVar(): ' + stringvar_name)
        if hasattr(focused, 'entry_name'):
            entry_name = getattr(focused, 'entry_name')
            self.who_text.insert(tk.END, 'tl.Entry : ' + entry_name)

    def clear_focus(self):
        self.root.focus()
        self.who_text.delete(0,tk.END)

    def close_it(self):
        self.root.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Focus_Get()
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I will definitely give this a test!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember to upvote and mark as accepted if this answer helps you.

Comment: Note that `self.root.focus_get()` will get the reference of the widget.  So calling `nametowidget()` on it is not necessary.

Comment: Quite right. Edited to remove the unnecessary call to `nametowidget()`.